# WPF Listbox SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I currently have an `Entity` that has a collection property on it. I want to know if why would the `SelectionChanged` only fire once and it won't trigger the `SelectionChanged` again once I try to select the item that was previously selected.

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
  public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var a = new List<Test>();

        a.Add(new Test() { Name = "Leo", Test1 = new List<Test1> { new Test1() { Content = "aaa"} } });
        a.Add(new Test() { Name = "2", Test1 = new List<Test1> { new Test1() { Content = "bbb"} } });
        a.Add(new Test() { Name = "Le33o", Test1 = new List<Test1> { new Test1() { Content = "ccc"} } });
        A = a;
    }

    private List<Test> _a;
    public List<Test> A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; OnPropertyChanged("A");}
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

**My Mainwindow**

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
        private void Test(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

**My listbox structure**

```
public class Test
{
    public List<Test1> Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get;set;
    }
}

public class Test1
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I select the first object, the event fires, I select the second object, the event fires, I select the first object, the event doesn't fire, I select third object, the event fires. It seems like it only triggers and calls the event once.

My `XAML` Code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Lists" ItemsSource="{Binding A}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                        Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" />

                    <ListBox  SelectionChanged="Test"  ItemsSource="{Binding Test1}"
                                 Margin="5,0,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The test method is just an empty method I just want to hit the breakpoint every time I change.

```
  private void Test(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

**Update 1**: I tried to reproduce this in a simple WPF app, it seems that the ListBoxItem is getting IsEnabled to false but I snooped it and all the controls are enabled. It just getting a grey background that looks like disabled. Will try to investigate further.

**Update 2**: It seems that the ListBoxItem IsSelected property is not being unset when you change an item.

Comment: I do not understand how the c# code is related to the XAML. You might want to be more precise.

Comment: Gave you the structure of the Entity that's why I have the C# code there, the xaml is how I bind it. It triggers fine and I tried reproducing it with different normal entities and it behaves the same.

Comment: You should post the code of your method "Test". I have a hard time believing this method doesn't run under the circumstances you are describing. You may not be getting the results you expect but that could be because of a flaw in the logic of the method. Did you try putting a breakpoint in "Test"?

Comment: Yes, I don't need to put the method for Test cause it is just empty method I just want it to fire. I did put a breakpoint.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing i know this is an very old post but doesn't fit my answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question ...

> *I want to know if why would the SelectionChanged only fire once and it won't trigger the SelectionChanged again once I try to select the
>   item that was previously selected.*

... in a learning by doing way

open a new WPF Project add 2 Listboxes create ONE SelectionChanged event for both and add some items to each Listbox

let's mention it look's now like this

```
    <ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox1" Width="120" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    <ListBox Height="100" Name="listBox2" Width="120" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

.

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Element1");
        list.Add("Element2");
        list.Add("Element3");
        list.Add("Element4");

        listBox1.ItemsSource = list;
        listBox2.ItemsSource = list;
```

If you now select `Element1` in `listBox1` your `listBox_SelectionChanged` get triggert after that select `Element2` in your `listBox2` so your `listBox_SelectionChanged` get's triggert again.

If you take a closer look at your `listBox1` you will see that the `Background` behind your `Element1` is gray which means it is selected, but with out focuse.  If you select now the  `Element1` in  your `listBox1` again the `listBox_SelectionChanged` doesn't get triggert because the selection does't change only the Focuse does.

That's the exact same "problem" is in your code because your `DataTemplate` does the same think we did as we added our 2 Listboxes just automatically

as simple and dirt workaround you could use the following code

```
    private object seletedItem;
    private ListBox ItemsHost;

    private void Test(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buff = sender as ListBox;

        if (seletedItem != null)
            if (ItemsHost != buff)
                ItemsHost.SelectedItem = null;

        ItemsHost = buff;

        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            seletedItem = e.AddedItems[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution I found out is to make `selectedItem` as `null` in the event handler.

```
private void tempList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

{    
    Card selectedOffer = (TempList.SelectedItem as Card);
    if (selectedOffer != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(selectedOffer._id);
    }
    ListBoxNeeded.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Selecting the same item is not a SelectionChanged event.  The selection did not change.

The problem statement is not clear.

Break it down.  This works for me.  If I select any item a second time, 3rd, 4th time the event fires.

OP asserted it does not work if it is a List in a List.  Still works for me.

```
    public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<ListList> ListList1 
        {
            get { return new List<ListList>{new ListList("name1", new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" })}; } 
        }

        private void Test(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lb.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }

        public class ListList
        {
            public string Name { get;  set; }
            public List<string> Values { get;  set; }
            public ListList(string name, List<string> values) { Name = name; Values = values; }
        }

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListList1}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox  SelectionChanged="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Not when you select another item and re-select that item.

Comment: The problem statement is "select the item that was previously selected".  Mark down your problem statement for not being clear rather than mark down this answer.

Comment: Acting like a kid now because someone marked your answer as down so you will mark the question as down. You should have ask in comment if something is not clear, not everyone in stackoverflow has good english. And how will you make it clear then? "Select the item that was previously selected" isn't that suppose to mean that you already selected that item before and you re-selected it?

Comment: I am marking the answer down because it is not clear.  One the item source is not valid - it does not have property Due Date.  Includes TextBlocks that don't appear to be part of the problem.  Three "re-select" is still not clear.  Clear would be:  Select an item the first time and the event fires.  Select another item for the first time and the event fires.  Selecting an item a second time does fire the event even if I select another item and come back.

Comment: One, it doesn't matter if the properties don't exist for some properties. You do know how to code in WPF do you?

Second, there is an edit option for the question to make it clear. And if that sentence you rephrase, you think it is clear for everyone then go edit for it and I will approve it.

Comment: You are the one with the question and you are asking if I can code.  Show some effort and clean up your own question.  Only post problem code with data to reproduce the problem is clearly going to produce better answers.

Comment: I am not asking you to code for me. I myself is investigating. It seems that the listboxitem on the child is getting disabled.

Comment: By the way, check my updated structure. Your solution will work as expected but try an entity that has a List property on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11837/discussion-between-leo-luis-and-blam)

Comment: List within a List Datatemplate and try changing the selection change. I think what you are trying to do is just List within a List with one hierarchy.

Comment: WHAT?  What part of this is not a 2 hierarchy List within a List?  public List<ListList> ListList1 
        {
            get { return new List<ListList>{new ListList("name1", new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" })}; } 
        }  And it works.